# Kali Linux multiple monitors setup

Tags: linux, kali-linux, display, monitors, display-settings

I have just installed Kali Linux 2.0 on dual boot. My computer has 3 monitors. 2 of them have DVI ports and are connected to my Nvidia Quadro 2000 GPU. The third monitor has VGA port and is connected to motherboard's GPU. The thing is that when I turn on my computer and launch Kali Linux, only the monitor connected motherboard's GPu turns on. The others stay off. At settings it only recognizes the monitor that is turned on. In my bios I have configured that motherboard's GPU will be primary. So I guess that is the problem. When I launch Windows 10 all the monitors turn on, but with Kali only the primary one. How can I manage to turn on the three monitors? Kali Linux recognizes only the primary one.

**NOTE:** The reason why I connect only 2 monitors to Nvidia GPU is that it only supports 2 ports active at a time, so I have to connect the other to the motherboard's GPU.

Comment: have you found a solution yet? I am having the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: I solved my problem by installing Nvidia video card driver.

Comment: Can you provide me a link please?

Comment: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?26526-Install-Nvidia-340-76-Driver-in-Kali-Linux-2-0

Comment: I could not install the drivers because I couldn't install headers-linux package. The error says unmet dependencies and I can't seem to update anything because of this !